# Port Forwarded Server Will broadcast to the Internet, not LAN

Tags: networking, ethernet, port-forwarding

I am hosting a server on another computer. This computer is wired with Ethernet cat5e cables , usually gets a 15ms ping, ~30mbps, and I cannot join through LAN on other computers. This server is port forwarded, and anyone on the Internet can connect. I have tried localhost, localhost:[port] [ip], [ip]:[port]. The computer I am trying to connect with is also wired with Ethernet cat5e cables, and also usually gets a 15ms ping, ~30mbps. Any help is appreciated.

Tripple

Comment: Are you connecting to the public IP address that everyone else does, the internal ip address given by the DHCP server, or another ip address? Seems like you are not using the right ip address. For example, if your server is hosted as 192.168.0.1, and you have ip address 192.168.0.2, you need to connect to the .1 not .2 and neither 127.0.0.1 or localhost, because they refer to .2 not .1

Comment: Also, if you’re still unable to connect: Is the PC otherwise reachable, via Remote Desktop/Ping/whatever?

Comment: The PC is reachable, but I checked the two computers ip's, and they have the same ip. I'm assuming this is from the wired network.

Comment: I have tried the public ip, the server does not give out an internal ip. It's a minecraft craftbukkit server, if that helps. And if you think it's childish i'm actually making money on it with advertising so shut up. :)

Comment: Two computers on the same network cannot have the same IP address. Please check again that you're connecting to the correct PC.

Answer (score 0):

Your router sucks and doesn't do NAT Loopback (also called "hairpin NAT"). Buy a better router or upgrade to firmware that does NAT loopback.